# create a shield on my character!(attach 2 sprites)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm pretty new on SpriteKit world I usually work with gamemakerstudio2. Anyway I have an issue, basically I don't know how to attach a shield above my character once my character pick the power up.  I know the collision part but I can't figure how to solve the problem of attach an image to another plus move both simultaneously! any hint? I don't know  maybe with physicjoint I can manage that but I want something different (in game maker I just fix a point on an object and the image will follow the object (setting x and y)) sorry for my bad English and maybe for the stupid question! Thanks for everyone that could answer that! have a nice day and take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it as a sprite with a higher zPosition to your character and then create some functions to turn it on and off in your player subclass

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {

    private var character: SKSpriteNode!
    private var isInvinsible = false

    init() {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: CGSize.zero)

        //setup your player code
        character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero")
        character.zPosition = 1
        addChild(character)

        setupShield()
    }

    func setupShield() {
        let shield = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shield")
        shield.zPosition = 10
        shield.isHidden = true
        addChild(shield)
    }

    func showShield() {
        shield.isHidden = false
        isInvinsible = true
    }

    func hideShield() {
        shield.isHidden = true
        isInvinsible = false
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir it worked as I want. sorry again for the stupid question! have a nice day my savior <3

Comment: great glad it helped you. because you are new I'll let you know, that if you find my answer helpful you can mark it up with the arrows. If it also answers your question please check mark it as correct

Comment: done! (I put the arrow up but stack says me that I'm new so that can't come up)